# Map to Set Mapping Workaround in Dozer

Tags: java, dozer

I'm trying to convert a Map to a Set in Dozer and I want to avoid having to write a custom converter at all costs. Is there anyway I can use the get-method attribute in the configuration file to get the collection of values from the set (Losing the key values isn't an issue) and have Dozer convert from that?

Here's what I've got so far, that isn't working

```
<field>
<a is-accessible="true" get-method="values">sourceMap</a>
<b>targetSet</b>
<a-hint>Destination</a-hint>
<b-hint>OtherDestination</b-hint>
</field>
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you must use a custom converter.

[This](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/documentation/collectionandarraymapping.html) shows how collections can be mapped. You can map specific entries in a map to a non collection variable as described [here](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/documentation/mapbackedproperty.html)